# Python Numba - How to debug caching to see when compilation happens

Tags: python-3.x, numba

I'm trying to determine when [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) is compiling or using a cached function.

Example:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit

@njit(cache=True)
def sq(x):
    return x**2

@njit(cache=True)
def f(x):
    return sq(x)*sq(x);

# scalar signature
x = 1
y = f(x)
# vector signature
x = np.asarray([1,2,3])
y = f(x)
```

Is there a way to have numba indicate when it compiles a function or uses the cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the environment variable `NUMBA_DEBUG_CACHE` to get more information, see https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/envvars.html#caching-options.

This could be done by adding

```py
import os
os.environ['NUMBA_DEBUG_CACHE'] = "1"
```

in front of your script.

When running your script you will find output lines like:

```
[cache] index saved to '/path/to/cache/script_name.something.nbi'
[cache] data saved to '/path/to/cache/script_name.something.nbc'
```

Which is what you are looking for